# How to calculate boolean symmetric difference ("Delat-Mesh") on two 3D meshes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array, mesh, boolean-operations

Update (2021-06-03): To clarify my question, since there has been no response so far

**I want to calculate the differences (boolean symmetric difference, XOR) of two 3D meshes** and save the determined "delta mesh" in a second step as a file in OBJ format.

**Is there a JavaScript implementation to calculate boolean symmetric difference?**

To clearify my question I added another picture:
[image]

For this purpose I have already implemented a code in JavaScript that reads two OBJ files and transfers them into arrays. The arrays each contain the vertices, the indices of the vertices for the description of the faces etc.

Result: (Shape_1 & Shape_2 are Input meshes (Model A & B) and Shape_3 is the desired output mesh to be calculated)

```
Shape_1_Vertices = {
    "array_3D_Mesh_1": [
        {
            "0": {
                "X": -25,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "1": {
                "X": -25,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 100
            }
        },
        {
            "2": {
                "X": -25,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "3": {
                "X": -25,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 100
            }
        },
        {
            "4": {
                "X": 25,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "5": {
                "X": 25,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 100
            }
        },
        {
            "6": {
                "X": 25,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "7": {
                "X": 25,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 100
            }
        }
    ]
}

Shape_1_Faces = {
    "array_FaceIndices_Mesh_1": [
        {
            "face0": {
                "1": 2,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "face1": {
                "1": 3,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "face2": {
                "1": 6,
                "2": 2,
                "3": 7
            }
        },
        {
            "face3": {
                "1": 7,
                "2": 2,
                "3": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "face4": {
                "1": 4,
                "2": 6,
                "3": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "face5": {
                "1": 5,
                "2": 6,
                "3": 7
            }
        },
        {
            "face6": {
                "1": 0,
                "2": 4,
                "3": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "face7": {
                "1": 1,
                "2": 4,
                "3": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "face8": {
                "1": 1,
                "2": 5,
                "3": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "face9": {
                "1": 3,
                "2": 5,
                "3": 7
            }
        },
        {
            "face10": {
                "1": 4,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 6
            }
        },
        {
            "face11": {
                "1": 6,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 2
            }
        }
    ]
}

Shape_2_Vertices = {
    "array_3D_Mesh_2": [
        {
            "0": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": -40,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "1": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": -40,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "2": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": 40,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "3": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": 40,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "4": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": -40,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "5": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": -40,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "6": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": 40,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "7": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": 40,
                "Z": 40
            }
        }
    ]
}

Shape_2_Faces = {
    "array_FaceIndices_Mesh_2": [
        {
            "face0": {
                "1": 0,
                "2": 4,
                "3": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "face1": {
                "1": 1,
                "2": 4,
                "3": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "face2": {
                "1": 2,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "face3": {
                "1": 3,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "face4": {
                "1": 6,
                "2": 2,
                "3": 7
            }
        },
        {
            "face5": {
                "1": 7,
                "2": 2,
                "3": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "face6": {
                "1": 4,
                "2": 6,
                "3": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "face7": {
                "1": 5,
                "2": 6,
                "3": 7
            }
        },
        {
            "face8": {
                "1": 7,
                "2": 3,
                "3": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "face9": {
                "1": 5,
                "2": 3,
                "3": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "face10": {
                "1": 4,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 6
            }
        },
        {
            "face11": {
                "1": 6,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 2
            }
        }
    ]
}

Shape_4_Vertices = {
    "array_3D_Mesh_4": [
        {
            "0": {
                "X": -25,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "1": {
                "X": -25,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 100
            }
        },
        {
            "2": {
                "X": -25,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "3": {
                "X": -25,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 100
            }
        },
        {
            "4": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": -40,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "5": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": -40,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "6": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "7": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "8": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "9": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "10": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": 40,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "11": {
                "X": -20,
                "Y": 40,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "12": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": -40,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "13": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": -40,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "14": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "15": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "16": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "17": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "18": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": 40,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "19": {
                "X": 20,
                "Y": 40,
                "Z": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "20": {
                "X": 25,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "21": {
                "X": 25,
                "Y": -15,
                "Z": 100
            }
        },
        {
            "22": {
                "X": 25,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "23": {
                "X": 25,
                "Y": 15,
                "Z": 100
            }
        }
    ]
}

Shape_4_Faces = {
    "array_FaceIndices_Mesh_4": [
        {
            "face0": {
                "1": 9,
                "2": 7,
                "3": 8
            }
        },
        {
            "face1": {
                "1": 8,
                "2": 7,
                "3": 6
            }
        },
        {
            "face2": {
                "1": 16,
                "2": 14,
                "3": 17
            }
        },
        {
            "face3": {
                "1": 17,
                "2": 14,
                "3": 15
            }
        },
        {
            "face4": {
                "1": 9,
                "2": 17,
                "3": 7
            }
        },
        {
            "face5": {
                "1": 7,
                "2": 17,
                "3": 15
            }
        },
        {
            "face6": {
                "1": 8,
                "2": 16,
                "3": 9
            }
        },
        {
            "face7": {
                "1": 9,
                "2": 16,
                "3": 17
            }
        },
        {
            "face8": {
                "1": 7,
                "2": 15,
                "3": 6
            }
        },
        {
            "face9": {
                "1": 6,
                "2": 15,
                "3": 14
            }
        },
        {
            "face10": {
                "1": 16,
                "2": 22,
                "3": 14
            }
        },
        {
            "face11": {
                "1": 14,
                "2": 22,
                "3": 20
            }
        },
        {
            "face12": {
                "1": 16,
                "2": 8,
                "3": 18
            }
        },
        {
            "face13": {
                "1": 18,
                "2": 8,
                "3": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "face14": {
                "1": 6,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 8
            }
        },
        {
            "face15": {
                "1": 8,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "face16": {
                "1": 6,
                "2": 14,
                "3": 4
            }
        },
        {
            "face17": {
                "1": 4,
                "2": 14,
                "3": 12
            }
        },
        {
            "face18": {
                "1": 6,
                "2": 4,
                "3": 7
            }
        },
        {
            "face19": {
                "1": 7,
                "2": 4,
                "3": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "face20": {
                "1": 15,
                "2": 7,
                "3": 13
            }
        },
        {
            "face21": {
                "1": 13,
                "2": 7,
                "3": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "face22": {
                "1": 9,
                "2": 17,
                "3": 11
            }
        },
        {
            "face23": {
                "1": 11,
                "2": 17,
                "3": 19
            }
        },
        {
            "face24": {
                "1": 15,
                "2": 13,
                "3": 14
            }
        },
        {
            "face25": {
                "1": 14,
                "2": 13,
                "3": 12
            }
        },
        {
            "face26": {
                "1": 16,
                "2": 18,
                "3": 17
            }
        },
        {
            "face27": {
                "1": 17,
                "2": 18,
                "3": 19
            }
        },
        {
            "face28": {
                "1": 4,
                "2": 12,
                "3": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "face29": {
                "1": 5,
                "2": 12,
                "3": 13
            }
        },
        {
            "face30": {
                "1": 9,
                "2": 11,
                "3": 8
            }
        },
        {
            "face31": {
                "1": 8,
                "2": 11,
                "3": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "face32": {
                "1": 18,
                "2": 10,
                "3": 19
            }
        },
        {
            "face33": {
                "1": 19,
                "2": 10,
                "3": 11
            }
        },
        {
            "face34": {
                "1": 6,
                "2": 7,
                "3": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "face35": {
                "1": 0,
                "2": 7,
                "3": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "face36": {
                "1": 1,
                "2": 7,
                "3": 15
            }
        },
        {
            "face37": {
                "1": 1,
                "2": 15,
                "3": 21
            }
        },
        {
            "face38": {
                "1": 21,
                "2": 15,
                "3": 20
            }
        },
        {
            "face39": {
                "1": 20,
                "2": 15,
                "3": 14
            }
        },
        {
            "face40": {
                "1": 2,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "face41": {
                "1": 3,
                "2": 0,
                "3": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "face42": {
                "1": 8,
                "2": 2,
                "3": 9
            }
        },
        {
            "face43": {
                "1": 9,
                "2": 2,
                "3": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "face44": {
                "1": 9,
                "2": 3,
                "3": 23
            }
        },
        {
            "face45": {
                "1": 9,
                "2": 23,
                "3": 17
            }
        },
        {
            "face46": {
                "1": 17,
                "2": 23,
                "3": 22
            }
        },
        {
            "face47": {
                "1": 17,
                "2": 22,
                "3": 16
            }
        },
        {
            "face48": {
                "1": 20,
                "2": 22,
                "3": 21
            }
        },
        {
            "face49": {
                "1": 21,
                "2": 22,
                "3": 23
            }
        },
        {
            "face50": {
                "1": 1,
                "2": 21,
                "3": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "face51": {
                "1": 3,
                "2": 21,
                "3": 23
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To clarify what I have in mind, I have attached a picture.
[image]

1. shows the initial bodies to be compared, which are available individually in OBJ format
2. shows the superimposed positioning of both bodies. (The positioning is automatically correct and as desired during import, so I don't have to worry about that).
3. shows the desired "delta mesh", which I want to calculate and output as a file in OBJ format. (The body in the dashed frame shows the intersection, which has to be cut out in the end, but is not of interest).

If you would want to realize my intention with boolean operations, you would have to perform boolean symmetric difference or XOR (exclusive OR).

I attached three files, wehre you can find the two input meshes and the desired output, which I want to calculate with an algorithm.

[Shape_1_Input_Model_A](http://www.filedropper.com/shape1)
[Shape_2_Input_Model_B](http://www.filedropper.com/shape2)
[Shape_4_Desired_Output http://www.filedropper.com/shape4](http://www.filedropper.com/shape4)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry is the name of this topic, and for JS in particular you could check ThreeCSG

Comment: I think you need to give us more details of the inputs and the expected outputs.  For instance, you list faces as items with three properties -- `1`, `2`, `3` -- each pointing to a string which is presumably the name of one of the vertices in your list of vertices.  But what do the indices mean?  And why, when everything seems to be rectangles, would your face be listed with three vertices instead of four?  While the pictures give some context, we need more complete and realistic data to work with.

Comment: @tevemadar: Thank you for your answer I will check this.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet: Thank you very much for your answer. I added another picture to illustrate my intention. The shown arrays of faces and vertices belong to the OBJ data structure, which can be seen on the left bottom corner on the new picture. I read the imported meshes in the OBJ-File format and transfer them into arrays to perform calculations on it. the final aim is to get an mesh of the boolean symmetric difference and export this...

Comment: @Mec-Eng: While extra pictures are great, what we really need in order to be able to answer this is actual realistic input data and the requested output.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet: Please excuse my inability and thank you for your patience with me. I have uploaded the three files and the links are now included in the question. [Shape_1_Input_Model_A](http://www.filedropper.com/shape1) [Shape_2_Input_Model_B](http://www.filedropper.com/shape2) [Shape_4_Desired_Output](http://www.filedropper.com/shape4)

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is still not input data to the question as asked.  Please read about creating a [mcve] and [ask] from the [help].  Would you please [edit] the question to include relevant JSON or similar data?  Ideally it would be a fairly small example, perhaps something like your two rectangular solids example above.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet: I added the JSON-Strings of shapes.  The JSON-Strings are eqaul to the OBJ-Data-Structure. You have one Array (for example Shape_2_Vertices) with numbered / indexed Points (x, y, z) and another array (for example Shape_2_Faces) with faces, where each face contains the obtained points by their index...  Btw. The colored shapes (green & brown) also includes the triangulated mesh, but it is NOT visible. Maybe this is a little bit confusing.

Comment: We're getting there!  Now do you have the expected output for these simple shapes?

Comment: The expected output is Shape_4, which is the boolean symmetric difference or XOR (exclusive or) of Shape_1 and Shape_2.